# C# ZipFile. How to extract or skip file with invalid characters in the name?

Tags: c#, exception, unzip, zip

I have a file named `“The Shooting Star”.jpeg` in a .zip archive.
When I try to extract it either via `ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory` or `ZipArchiveEntry.ExtractToFile`, I get `System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path` exception.

Such file is successfully extracted via WinRar.

Is there a way to avoid the exception using ZipFile and successfully extract the file or at least skip such file?

**Update:**

Uploaded the said archive: [The Archive](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=33518858241197167825)

Comment: Why do you have quotes in your file name? You can't have those in a standard Windows file name, so it should be pretty clear where the issue is.

Comment: @DangerZone, those are special symbols, not " quotes, so they work.

Comment: Ah, didn't notice that.

Comment: Do you have any other strange characters? I was not able to replicate your problem with any equally name files using the same `ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory()` method.

Comment: @DangerZone, I do not. I specifically tested and these: “” characters are the problem. Windows Explorer fails to extract file with those in the name too. I am using Windows 7 if that matters.

Comment: Could you post a full code example with this failing? I would like to try it out and see what's happening.

Comment: @DangerZone, It fails on either ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory or ZipArchiveEntry.ExtractToFile (when I try to loop through files), just if you wonder I will upload the said archive in the post.

Answer (score 0):

You can reformat the source name to remove illegal character from sourcename.

```
 var illegalChars = Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars();
 var destName = sourceName.Where(x => !illegalChars.Contains(x)).Aggregate("", (current, x) => current + x);
```

sourceName is the file name in the archive, then you can use ZipArchiveEntry.ExtractToFile and give it a rectified destination file name.

Comment: I can't access the file in the archive at all, that is the issue.